# GCC toolchain for ARC Arctangent A4

Tags: gcc, toolchain

Where can I find GCC toolchain for Arctangent A4 processors?

I know it was available at one point because of this post
 http://gcc.gcc.gnu.narkive.com/nbyfc8Vw/porting-gcc-4-x-on-tangent-a4. Unfortunately, the company that used to maintain the code (Azingo) seems to have been bought up by Motorolla and the website mentioned in the post is no longer up. Neither are there websites under other names used by Azingo prior to its acquisition.

There are two existing GCC Arc toolchains I was able to find neither of which works for A4, though for different reasons.
1. There is a toolchain for the newer Arc CPUs based on ArcCompact ISA at
https://github.com/foss-for-synopsys-dwc-arc-processors/toolchain/ which is not compatible with A4.
2. There is also support for the A4 in GCC trunk that has bit-rotted and does not build.

Comment: You still have one of those and really want to use it? Hmm, ok. The first thing I would try is using an old enough version of gcc that the tangent support hadn't bit-rotted yet. Since compiling older versions of gcc with newer ones can be tricky, I would install a very old distribution in a VM for this.

Comment: Thank you, Marc. I will give it a try. I need this for an RE project. I realize that A4 is pretty obscure hardware at this point but the devices that use it are still around.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be nearly impossible to compile old arc-gcc versions. Some posts to sourceware mailing suggest that out-of-tree patches may be required and it is unclear which patches are required and where to get them (e.g. https://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2001-05/msg00159.html).

After much searching, however, I found this site https://www.maintech.de/en/support/toolchains/ that has a prebuilt arc-gcc toolchain with A4 support.

Answer (score 0):

One more source is old Metaware [ARCGCC toolchains on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/arc-linux/files/ARC%20GNU%20Toolchain/). I have not tried building them, possibly they need old GCC.